# How to identify table row id dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic

I have to find out table row id. For that I am writing the code

```
match1[i].setTextSize(12);
            match1[i].setPadding(10,0,0,0);
            tr.addView(match1[i]);
            Log.e("TAG", "ID: "+match1[i].getId());
            match1[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {       
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Toast.makeText(SAXParserActivity.this, ""+tr.getId(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("TAG", " clicked ID: "+tr.getId());
                }
            });
     t1.addView(tr, tableRowParams);
```

where match1 is a text view. All is working fine but the problem is on clicking table row. For each row I am getting -1 id, but before on click the id is coming correctly. Please suggest where is the mistake, and how can I display data randomly after parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Snippet :

```
final View row=contact_table.getChildAt(i);
row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v){
    row_id=contact_table.indexOfChild(row);
   }
});
```

where contact_table is your TableLayout object

Answer (score 0):

As Cursor always points just before the 1st row, that means -1. You should use "moveToFirst()" to get to the first row

```
eg: 

   for(cursor.moveToFirst() ; !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){

            // Do whatever u want with the data obtained
}
```